# Insertar datos en una tabla con php y my sql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola requiero insertar datos en una tabla llamada categories, sin embargo no logro el resultado que deseo , lo que quiero es insertar el nombre de la categoría y que se agregue un id automáticamente, aca muestro el codigo que estoy usando tambien seria genial si se pudieran eliminar datos desde el front, desconozco bastante php, el codigo que estoy usando es un CRUD llamado hamburguer code [https://obedalvarado.pw/blog/restaurant-menu-php-script-gratis/][1] .

````
    
   require 'database.php';

  $name = "";

   if(!empty($_POST)) 
   {
       $name               = checkInput($_POST['name']);
       $isSuccess          = true;
       $isUploadSuccess    = false;
       
       if(empty($name)) 
       {
           $nameError = 'Este campo no puede estar vacío';
           $isSuccess = false;
       }
       
       if($isSuccess) 
       {
           $db = Database::connect();
           $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO categories (name) values(?)");
           $statement->execute(array($name));
           Database::disconnect();
           header("Location: index.php");
       }
   }

   function checkInput($data) 
   {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
   }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <?php include("head.php")?>
   </head>
   
   <body>
       <h1 class="text-logo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span> App Menu <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span></h1>
        <div class="container admin">
           <div class="row">
               <h1><strong>Categoria</strong></h1>
               <br>
               <form class="form" action="insert.php" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $name;?>">

                   </div>
                   <br>
                   <div class="form-actions">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Agregar</button>
                       <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Regresar</a>
                  </div>
               </form>
           </div>
       </div>   
   </body>
</html>  ```


 [1]: https://obedalvarado.pw/blog/restaurant-menu-php-script-gratis/
````

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo, a que le quieres agregar un id automaticamente? a la tabla categories?

Answer (score 1):

Si aún te sirve, a tu tabla debes agregar un campo `OID` por ejemplo, lo seteas como clave primaria y le dices que será auto incremental. Con eso no necesitas enviarle parámetro desde `php` sino que el motor de `mySql` lo agrega cada vez que insertas un registro.

Desde `phpMyAdmin` es así de sencillo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente , muchas Gracias